# Something Very Weird about ASP Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i made a GridView in Asp with 1 BoundField,1 Button Field,1 command field ,1 template field with Button inside and here is code

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="rdGrid" ForeColor="#333333" BorderWidth="1px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="View Summary" CommandName="Summary" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-small" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White" />
        <asp:CommandField EditText="Edit" ShowEditButton="true" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-small" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White"></asp:CommandField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-small" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Player?');" />
                  <%--<asp:HiddenField id="rdId" Value='<%# Eval("roundId") %>' runat="server" />--%>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and this is output i am getting .. something very weird
and hidden field Eval Says it doesn't exist in current context giving out an Exception .. that's why i commented hidden field..

Code used to Bind Grid

```
 string cs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        MySqlConnection register = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        register.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM rounds;", register);
        MySqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "rounds");
        register.Close();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables["rounds"];
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("Description");
        dt1.Columns.Add("roundId");
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dt1.NewRow();
            string des = dr["Description"].ToString();
            string rid=dr["roundId"].ToString();
            dt1.ImportRow(dr);
            string[] arr1D = { des,rid };
        }
        rdGrid.DataSource = dt1;
        rdGrid.DataBind();
        rdGrid.RowCommand += rdGrid_RowCommand;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your Image with grid view you have two columns as description, it seems you have to put 
`AutoGenerateColumns` as false in your grid view as below

```
<asp:GridView runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="rdGrid" ForeColor="#333333" BorderWidth="1px">
```

than you will not get additional description column in UI.

And also if you binding more columns, they should also appear as auto generated columns. but now you have only the description column.

You may need to change the select statement to fetch all the columns you need

```
select roundId, Description, ....  from YourTable
```

Comment: :it worked .. any help with Hiddenfield Eval ?? it says it doesnt exist in current context .. giving an exception

Comment: @SiddharthKoya can you update the question with the code how you bind data to grid?

Comment: Hello Damith.. Sorry for Delay .. I Updated the Question with Code to Bind the Grid

Answer (score 0):

For the round ID I think you use the DataKeyNames attribute of gridview.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx